# How to sort a hash by the values of another array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

Looks like a piece of cake, but can't solve it..

```
elements = ['one', 'two', 'three']

sort_me = {'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

`sort_me.sort_by { |k, _| elements.index k }.to_h` does not sort it the way it should. The hash stays the same.

The desired output is `{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}`.

Comment: in this Hash `{'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}` are symbols e.g. `{three: 3, two: 2, one: 1}` so your sort just needs to change to `sort_me.sort_by { |k, _| elements.index k.to_s }.to_h` or your `Array` needs to be `[:one,:two,:three]`

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Comment: @engineersmnky's code has a computational complexity of O((n^2)log(n)), nlog(n) for the sort, n for finding the index. You can reduce that to O(n) with `arr = elements.map(&:to_sym); arr.zip(sort_me.values_at(*arr)).to_h #=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}`. See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at). For some reason the latter method seems to be greatly underutilised.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes I had already determined that appears to be the fastest mechanism. Just figured that explaining the issue made more sense than going through a process that no longer looks like sort. P.S. in >= 2.6 you can do `elements.map(&:to_sym).then {|arr| arr.zip(sort_me.values_at(*arr)).to_h }` in one pretty line :)

Comment: @engineersmnky, a very pretty line... katericata, whenever you need to do something like this think of the word "rearrange" rather than "sort", as the latter tends to bring to mind sorting methods, which are often not the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to sort anything, and you also don't need to create a lookup table. Your array is already sorted the way you want and your `sort_me` hash is already a lookup table:

```
elements = ['one', 'two', 'three']
# => ["one", "two", "three"]
sort_me = {'three' => 3, 'two' => 2, 'one' => 1}
# => {"three"=>3, "two"=>2, "one"=>1}
elements.map{|key| [key, sort_me[key] ] }.to_h
# => {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3}
```

If you want to use symbols and strings:

```
elements = ['one', 'two', 'three']
# => ["one", "two", "three"]
sort_me = {three: 3, two: 2, one: 1}
# => {:three=>3, :two=>2, :one=>1}
elements.map{|key| [key.to_sym, sort_me[key.to_sym] ] }.to_h
# => {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
```

Finally, if some `elements` are not used in the hash, you could simply remove pairs with `nil` values:

```
elements = ['one', 'two', 'two_and_a_half', 'three']
# => ["one", "two", "two_and_a_half", "three"]
elements.map{|key| [key.to_sym, sort_me[key.to_sym] ] }.to_h
# => {:one=>1, :two=>2, :two_and_a_half=>nil, :three=>3}
elements.map{|key| [key.to_sym, sort_me[key.to_sym] ] }.reject{|k, v| v.nil? }.to_h
# => {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh Gosh.. I am creating a hash of symbol keys and I want to sort it with an array of strings. Looks like my Python background tricked me here.

`sort_me = {'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}` results to 
`=> {:three=>3, :two=>2, :one=>1}`

Let's convert the hash key into string to get the sorting work:

`sort_me.sort_by { |k,_| elements.index k.to_s }.to_h`